# how i can color only some parts of a picture using js

Tags: javascript, image, colors

I am trying to color some parts of a png image "only some parts " and I was thinking about using edge detection then coloring area.

Is there are any easier method to do it using canevas or any other js APIs ?

This an example of what i want:

[image: example]

Comment: You should provide some code or at least some detailed explanation of what you have tried so far and what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Probably canvas, maybe a library will help.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? In the provided example there's a motorcycle, but how are "only some parts" distinguished by your script? Which parts are chosen? And what for?

Comment: i tried canva librery i will give some  code to explane

Answer (score 0):

Most js image processing libraries fall into three main categories:

1. **Filter**: using canvas and simple pixel processing to adjust the image with hue, saturation, contrast etc. e.g. pixastic, CamanJs
2. **Presentation**: custom animation and positioning of images based, sometimes content-aware. e.g. flip, smart backgorund.
3. **Processing**: include complex processing algorithms, ones that are usually employed in applications such as face recognition or post-processing.

I believe the library that comes closest to your need is **JSFeat** since it includes complex image processing such as HAAR object detection:

https://github.com/inspirit/jsfeat